# Convert xml to java

Tags: java, xml

How can I convert xml to java so that it could read the xml document and put it in to a database?

Comment: This makes sense. He's looking for an object builder, much like GSON does for JSON.

Comment: You question is very unclear - I read it to mean that you are looking for a way to read an XML file and save it into a database.

Comment: You certainly can't convert XML (markup language) to Java (programming language). Do you mean that how to make a Java program that takes a XML document in and puts its contents into a database?

Comment: Joonas, your answer is wrong. You can unmarshall XML to Java POJOs, which can then be automatically written to a database via an ORM. You CAN convert XML to java so that it can be put in a database, if you know the technology stack required to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this: http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.xml.parsers/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java.html
That's how you read xml file. Then you just crate SQL query to insert it into database (JDBC?)

Comment: great this is what im looking for now i want to know how do i create the sql database

Answer (score 6):

Your question is rather obscure and general. There are a number of options for converting XML to Java objects:

- [JAXB](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/WebServices/jaxb/)
- [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/)
- [XMLBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/)

[This article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2000/jw-0804-sax.html) could be useful.

But anyway you will have to read much before getting something more complex to work.

This is all in case you need to map your xml to java *objects*. If you just need to parse the XML:

- [dom4j](http://www.dom4j.org/)
- [xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/)
- [JAXP](https://jaxp.dev.java.net/)

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear at all, but if you are talking about parsing a XML file to do whatever you want with it in Java (also storing it in a database) you have to already ready choices:

- using a **DOM** parser
- using a **SAX** parser

both are covered [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0408.html) just to give you an example, but check documentation for  better explaination.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently [JAXB](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/WebServices/jaxb/) can do marshalling/unmarshalling. I've not used it, but it seems to do what you want. From there, you can use an ORM of some type to put your objects in a database, or you can handcraft SQL.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for something like [JAXB](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/WebServices/jaxb/) or [Castor](http://www.castor.org/). They both let you convert from a Java object -> XML and XML -> Java object.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Hyperjaxb3](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/HJ3/Purchase+Order+Tutorial). It is a JAXB plugin which makes schema-derived classes to JPA entities. Thus you can easily do XML <-(JAXB)-> Java <-(JPA)-> RDB.

Answer (score 0):

For this I recommend [EclipseLink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/).  EclipseLink offers both [JAXB (object-to-XML)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) and [JPA (object-to-Database)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/jpa.php) support.

The EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) implementation offers all the extensions you need for mapping JPA entities to XML, for more information see:

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/JPA

Answer (score 0):

Use this https://json2csharp.com/xml-to-java in case you're looking for an online tool, you can then deserialize your object and fill it in the database